# webservice receives array of parameters as string not as array

Tags: php, ios, web-services

I have developed a web service using php(zend) which receives array of parameters from ios app, but when the ios app sends the parameters, the web service receives them as string, and I can't convert it into array so I can't handle the request

received string format like this

```
  (
            {
            "parm1" = "val1";
            "parm2" = val2;
            "parm3" = val4;
            }
    )
```

How can I convert this json into array?

Comment: already u getting array bro

Comment: Use json_decode function to convert it into array.

Answer (score 2):

Consider you are getting

```
$json = ' (
            {
            "parm1" = "val1";
            "parm2" = val2;
            "parm3" = val4;
            }
    )';
$array = json_decode($json,true); // this is the array
```

And you will get parameters :

```
$parm1 = $array->parm1;
$parm2 = $array->parm2;
$parm3 = $array->parm3;
```

`json_decode` takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a array.

Comment: Looks like you copied it from me.. +1

Comment: Yes, It look like that but bro when there is one answer then that may look somewhat same.

Comment: I was talking about this comment // this is the array . There is no change in that

Answer (score 1):

It looks like JSON format. Pass this string to method [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and it will convert it to an array for you (or any other object it was encoded from).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `json_decode` to decode this json into array. Use the code below

```
$json = ' (
            {
            "parm1" = "val1";
            "parm2" = val2;
            "parm3" = val4;
            }
    )';
$array = json_decode($json,true); // this is the array
```

Hope this helps you